# GET flash file(.swf) 404 error

Tags: html, flash

I just try to place a flash file in my site, but I see I get the 404 error.
I have looked for the flash file on the server and it exist, so I don't thinks it's the issue.
I attach the code, and the error as well.

The code:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="480" height="430" id="move3" align="middle" viewastext>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="movie" value="/FilesDB/View3D/Movie_objID_3426_typeID_5.swf?NoCashe=1570316002" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#989866" />
    <embed src="/FilesDB/View3D/Movie_objID_3426_typeID_5.swf?NoCashe=1570316002" 
        quality="high" 
        bgcolor="#989866" 
        width="480" 
        height="430" 
        name="move3" 
        align="middle" 
        allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" 
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
        pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
    />
    </object>
```

The error:
GET http://www.loveandpride.com/FilesDB/View3D/Movie_objID_3426_typeID_5.swf?NoCashe=1570316002 404 (Not Found)

Hope you can help me...
Ben

Comment: It seems you already fixed the problem, I can download the file now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is some misconfiguration of iis web site; infact 
http://www.loveandpride.com/FilesDB
just response a 404 error,
http://www.loveandpride.com/FilesDB/View3D/
too.

Maybe FilesDb is configured as virtual directory pointing to an not existent location?

Comment: thanks for the quick response. What kind of configuration could it be? the site loads ok...

Comment: The FilesDB directory does exists?

Comment: I see you have fixed. Please accept the answer if it is useful for your problem.

Comment: The fileDB does exist. I can see the flash now but I'm still not sure I got the right solution: The FileDB, View3D directories were both hidden, as well as the flash file inside. So I just unchecked the hidden checkbox and I also gave full permissions on the 2 folders. I'm afraid the folders were hidden for a reason and I made a mistake..

Comment: Update: I just have removed the permissions and I made the 2 folders hidden again. The only change I have kept is the flash files are no more hidden. Do you think it's Ok?

Comment: It is ok if it is your intended behaviour, i.e. to make the two folders not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `viewastext` from your `object` element.

> The viewastext attribute prevents an authoring tool from running the object at design time. This attribute is not required if you do not use these tools and note that it can cause problems in some environments; for example strict xhtml documents.

Source: http://www.meadroid.com/scriptx/docs/printdoc.asp

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, actually I don't need it to run at design time or in a strict xhtml page